# align blocks side by side inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Thanks for the great job in here.

I'm having hard time to align blocks side by side inside a div. I know its not that complicated but I just cant find a nice way to do it......

Html here :

```
<div class="test">
   test
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div id="header_logo"></div>
         <div id="tmsearch" class="clearfix">
            <span class="btn-toogle active"></span>
            <form id="tmsearchbox">
               <input name="controller" value="search" type="hidden">
               <input name="orderby" value="position" type="hidden">
               <input name="orderway" value="desc" type="hidden">
               <input class="tm_search_query form-control ac_input" id="tm_search_query" name="search_query" placeholder="What are you shopping for today ?" value="" autocomplete="off" type="text">
            </form>
            <button class="submit-buttons" id="search-bar-button" type="submit">Search</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JSiddle here  https://jsfiddle.net/x7juoq64/6/

I would appreciate some help from the front end devs community and pardon me for my newbie question.

Comment: If you are processing the form then button should be inside <form> which will handle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `display: flex` to any parent element that has children you want to display side by side.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="test flex">
   test
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div id="header_logo"></div>
         <div id="tmsearch" class="clearfix flex">
            <span class="btn-toogle active"></span>
            <form id="tmsearchbox" class="flex">
               <input name="controller" value="search" type="hidden">
               <input name="orderby" value="position" type="hidden">
               <input name="orderway" value="desc" type="hidden">
               <input class="tm_search_query form-control ac_input" id="tm_search_query" name="search_query" placeholder="What are you shopping for today ?" value="" autocomplete="off" type="text">
            </form>
            <button class="submit-buttons" id="search-bar-button" type="submit">Search</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `flex` sure is very useful

Comment: @Michael Thanks very helpful and fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add that line to each block style attribute 
    float:left;

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
#search-bar-button,
.tm_search_query
{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  test
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="header_logo"></div>
      <div id="tmsearch" class="clearfix">
        <span class="btn-toogle active"></span>
        <form id="tmsearchbox">
          <input name="controller" value="search" type="hidden">
          <input name="orderby" value="position" type="hidden">
          <input name="orderway" value="desc" type="hidden">
          <input class="tm_search_query form-control ac_input" id="tm_search_query" name="search_query" placeholder="What are you shopping for today ?" value="" autocomplete="off" type="text">
        </form>
        <button class="submit-buttons" id="search-bar-button" type="submit">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually , I would like test -> search bar -> search button

Comment: Check @Michael's answer

Answer (score 0):

Form is a block level element like a div.

I forked your fiddle here with a remedy: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LyLhco3n/2/)

I simply added:

`form { display: inline-block; }`

to the css and your inputs display inline.

Update*
Note: display:flex is less browser supported at the moment. 
[W3CSchools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp)

Hope this helps